# Installing MSI package gives BadImageFormatException

Tags: badimageformatexception

I have a MSI package (x64) created in VS Professional 2010 (10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel), .NET 4.5.50709 SP1Rel , Windows 7
 It contains a windows service, other dlls and 3rd party dlls.
 It was working without any problem until I added a reference to a x64.net(2.0) dll compiled under VS2005.
 The error I am getting now is:

MSI (s) (74:A0) [12:23:10:931]: Generating random cookie.
 MSI (s) (74:A0) [12:23:10:933]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 13876 (0x3634).
 MSI (s) (74:DC) [12:23:10:954]: Running as a service.
 MSI (s) (74:DC) [12:23:10:955]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Elevated custom action server.
 MSI (s) (74!E4) [12:38:33:692]: Creating MSIHANDLE (84) of type 790531 for thread 9444
 DEBUG: Error 2835:  The control ErrorIcon was not found on dialog ErrorDialog
 The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2835. The arguments are: ErrorIcon, ErrorDialog, 
 Error 1001. Error 1001. Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
 System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\xyz\xyz Manager\xyz.Service.exe' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format..
 MSI (s) (74!E4) [12:39:24:631]: 
 MSI (s) (74:38) [12:39:24:634]: Leaked MSIHANDLE (84) of type 790531 for thread 9444
 MSI (s) (74:38) [12:39:24:634]: Note: 1: 2769 2: _57DBC9CE_7D15_455B_8B30_5B2EB10DF0BB.install 3: 1 
 DEBUG: Error 2769:  Custom Action _57DBC9CE_7D15_455B_8B30_5B2EB10DF0BB.install did not close 1 MSIHANDLEs.
 The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2769. The arguments are: _57DBC9CE_7D15_455B_8B30_5B2EB10DF0BB.install, 1, 
 CustomAction _57DBC9CE_7D15_455B_8B30_5B2EB10DF0BB.install returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
 MSI (s) (74:38) [12:39:24:636]: Closing MSIHANDLE (83) of type 790536 for thread 12548
 Action ended 12:39:24: InstallExecute. Return value 3.
 MSI (s) (74:04) [12:39:24:649]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
 MSI (s) (74:04) [12:39:24:650]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
 MSI (s) (74:04) [12:39:24:653]: Executing op: Header(Signature=1397708873,Version=500,Timestamp=1118855907,LangId=1033,Platform=589824,ScriptType=2,ScriptMajorVersion=21,ScriptMinorVersion=4,ScriptAttributes=1)
 MSI (s) (74:04) [12:39:24:653]: Executing op: DialogInfo(Type=0,Argument=1033)
 MSI (s) (74:04) [12:39:24:654]: Executing op: DialogInfo(Type=1,Argument=xyz)
 MSI (s) (74:04) [12:39:24:654]: Executing op: RollbackInfo(,RollbackAction=Rollback,RollbackDescription=Rolling back action:,RollbackTemplate=[1],CleanupAction=RollbackCleanup,CleanupDescription=Removing backup files,CleanupTemplate=File: [1])
 Action 12:39:24: Rollback. Rolling back action:
 Rollback: _57DBC9CE_7D15_455B_8B30_5B2EB10DF0BB.install
 MSI (s) (74:04) [12:39:24:655]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=_57DBC9CE_7D15_455B_8B30_5B2EB10DF0BB.install,,)
 MSI (s) (74:04) [12:39:24:656]: Executing op: ProductInfo(ProductKey={7C3F562E-7D0F-49B6-AFE1-7DD5C4EBD2C2},ProductName=xyz Manager,PackageName=Setup.msi,Language=1033,Version=33554432,Assignment=1,ObsoleteArg=0,ProductIcon=_853F67D554F05449430E7E.exe,,PackageCode={DAA1A94E-2679-4076-A4CF-0F7B1E839A86},,,InstanceType=0,LUASetting=0,RemoteURTInstalls=0,ProductDeploymentFlags=3)
 Rollback: _A57B6B8D_EBFF_40E0_82DD_21B8F6E64792
 MSI (s) (74:04) [12:39:24:657]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=_A57B6B8D_EBFF_40E0_82DD_21B8F6E64792,,)
 Rollback: _3CB427CA_9552_4B3E_9238_DC91BB0F603B.rollback
 MSI (s) (74:04) [12:39:24:658]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=_3CB427CA_9552_4B3E_9238_DC91BB0F603B.rollback,,)
 MSI (s) (74:04) [12:39:24:659]: Executing op: CustomActionRollback(Action=_3CB427CA_9552_4B3E_9238_DC91BB0F603B.rollback,ActionType=3329,Source=BinaryData,Target=ManagedInstall,CustomActionData=/installtype=notransaction /action=rollback /LogFile= "C:\Program Files\xyz\xyz Manager\xyz.Service.exe" "C:\Users\abc~1.STO\AppData\Local\Temp\CFG2C18.tmp")
 MSI (s) (74:04) [12:39:24:693]: Creating MSIHANDLE (85) of type 790536 for thread 12548
 MSI (s) (74:C4) [12:39:24:693]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI29ED.tmp, Entrypoint: ManagedInstall
 MSI (s) (74!88) [12:39:24:727]: Creating MSIHANDLE (86) of type 790531 for thread 12424
 DEBUG: Error 2835:  The control ErrorIcon was not found on dialog ErrorDialog
 The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2835. The arguments are: ErrorIcon, ErrorDialog,
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2835. The arguments are: ErrorIcon, ErrorDialog, 
 Error 1001. Error 1001. Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
 System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\xyz\xyz Manager\xyz.Service.exe' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format..
 MSI (s) (74!88) [12:59:18:001]: 
 MSI (s) (74:C4) [12:59:18:016]: Leaked MSIHANDLE (86) of type 790531 for thread 12424
 MSI (s) (74:C4) [12:59:18:016]: Note: 1: 2769 2: _3CB427CA_9552_4B3E_9238_DC91BB0F603B.rollback 3: 1 
 DEBUG: Error 2769:  Custom Action _3CB427CA_9552_4B3E_9238_DC91BB0F603B.rollback did not close 1 MSIHANDLEs.
 The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2769. The arguments are: _3CB427CA_9552_4B3E_9238_DC91BB0F603B.rollback, 1, 
 CustomAction _3CB427CA_9552_4B3E_9238_DC91BB0F603B.rollback returned actual error code 1603 but will be translated to success due to continue marking
 MSI (s) (74:C4) [12:59:18:017]: Closing MSIHANDLE (85) of type 790536 for thread 12548
 Rollback: _1D90AC8C_CBD2_432C_8C03_8E17E724219A

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is basic but did you try running msiexec /i "yourmsi.msi" from an elevated command prompt? Just to remove lack of elevated permission error implications.

Comment: Also do you have source code for the 2005 DLL? Can you recompile with VS2010?

Comment: I tried msiexec /i "yourmsi.msi and did'nt work.
I don't have 2005 dll source code, also I updated msi package as described here: [link]http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2006/02/01/64-bit-managed-custom-actions-with-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: can you exclude the 2005 DLL, and then script it to be placed into system32 or the proper location(s)? then you can do a regsvr and register the DLL with Windows afterwards.

Comment: 2005 dll is a .net dll, no need to register it with regsvr, the main application is a windows service, every thing is installed correctly, then there is a delay for  few minutes and I think it failed to add the .exe file to windows services.

Comment: do you have a Commit custom action?

Comment: yes, the install custom action will install another setupex.exe before installing our primary output from Service.

Comment: Problem solved after removing VS2012 C#, reinstallation of VS2010 and other 3rd parties application.

It was working for more than 3 years without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after removing VS2012 C#, reinstallation of VS2010 and other 3rd parties application.

It was working for more than 3 years without any problem.